# C++ serial communication write speed

Tags: python, c++, windows, serial-port

I'm using uPyCraft IDE and Putty For communicating with serial "COM3" Port.

and I make a new C++ console Application for using serial port now.

but C++ console application's  running speed is slower than Pychon.

How can I improve performance? is my code is something wrong?

this is what I tried in C++

```
int serialib::writeBytes(const void *Buffer, const unsigned int NbBytes)
{
    DWORD dwBytesWritten;
    if(!WriteFile(hSerial, Buffer, NbBytes, &dwBytesWritten, NULL))
        return -1;
    return 1;
}

void writedata(const char * arg)
{
 string result = arg;
 serial.writeBytes(&result,sizeof(result));
}

int main()
{
 serial.openDevice("COM3", 115200);
 if (serial.isDeviceOpen() != true)
 {
  return 1;
 }
 for (int i = 1;i <= 1000;i++)
 {
  writedata("km.move(0,1) ");
 }
}
```

this is what I tried in Putty or uPyCraft

```
for i in range(1000) : km.move(0,1)
```

I couldn't find what point did I wrong

Speed is different more than double.

Putty and uPyCraft is Faster than C++ console

I don't know is writedata function causing delay

What is the best code for at C++ Console, writeBytes to commuinating with serial?

p.s : BaudRate, ByteSize, Stopbits, Pariety is same

```
BaudRate : 115200
ByteSize : 8
StopBits : 1
Pariety : NONE (0)
```

Comment: Can you change `serial.writeBytes(&result, sizeof(result)) ` to `serial.writeBytes(result.c_str(), result.size())` and check the result?

Comment: @nomoresigsegv i tried it now and when i change it to `serial.writeBytes(result.c_str(), result.size())` it doesn't work

Comment: `sizeof(result)` will always yield the same number (32 i guess). That's not the data length, that's the size of `std::string` class. I don't know why my suggestion didn't work for you but it's the way to go.

Comment: @nomoresigsegv i found something, my writeBytes Code doesn't work when i using this code `writedata("km.move(0,1)");` but this code works fine `writedata("km.move(0,10)");` and also this code works fine `writedata("km.move(0,1) ");` , `writedata("km.press('a')");`. i think it only work when string length == 13. i need your help, how can i fix it you think?

Comment: i don't know why but it only works when str length == 13 and size should be 32 like this
`serial.writeBytes(result.c_str(),32)` `writedata("km.press('a')");`

Comment: Please do what I suggested in the first comment, rebuild your project (clean first), if it does not work i'm afraid something else is wrong with your code. `serial.writeBytes(&result,sizeof(result));` is not going to work.

Comment: @nomoresigsegv it doesn't work and seriously, `DWORD dwBytesWritten; string str = "km.move(0,1)"; WriteFile(m_hComm,str.c_str(),str.size(),&dwBytesWritten,NULL);` it doesn't work too